# using ode45 to solve y'=y adnd y'=t in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, ode, scientific-computing, differential-equations

I first defined functions for dy/dt=y and dy/dt=t:

```
function dy=d(y):
    dy=y
end

function ddy=dd(t):
    ddy=t
end
```

And then I used ode45, respectively:

```
[t,y]=ode45('d',[1 10],1)
[t,y]=ode45('dd',[1 10],1)
```

which returns the following error: Error using d
Too many input arguments.

My question is:

1. Where did I go wrong?
2. How does Matlab know whether y or t is the independent variable? When I define the first function, it could be reasonably interpreted as dt/dy=y instead of dy/dt=y. Is there a built-in convention for defining functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: the docs on [`ode45`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) are on the mathworks website, or you can get them from the console by entering `help ode45`.

The function you pass in needs to take two variables, `y` then `t`. As you noticed, with just one it would be impossible to distinguish a function of only `y` from a function of only `t`. The first argument has to be the independent, the second is the dependent.

Try defining your function as `dy = d(t, y)` and `ddy = dd(t, y)` with the same bodies.

one other note, while using a string representing the function name should work, you can use `@d` and `@dd` to reference the functions directly.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful.